# Source of Android's lock screen

Tags: android, android-source

I am looking for the source code of the android lock screen. It can be for any version of Android (1.5, 1.6, 2.0, etc).

I tried looking in the repository at: https://android.googlesource.com/, but it doesn't look like it's under `platform/frameworks/base`. Maybe it's closed source?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Do an actual full checkout of the source according to [Google's directions](http://source.android.com/source/downloading.html).

As of Android 4.2, the keyguard source is at `frameworks/base/policy/src/com/android/internal/policy/impl/keyguard`. There's a [mirror on GitHub](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/tree/jb-mr1.1-release/policy/src/com/android/internal/policy/impl/keyguard) you can look at online (I pegged this link to the JB MR 1.1 release in case the location changes again in a future release).

When this question was originally answered, Android 2.3 and lower had their lockscreen source at `frameworks/policies/base/phone/com/android/internal/policy/impl`.
You can also view [these sources online in their GitHub mirror](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_policies_base/blob/master/phone/com/android/internal/policy/impl/); that source is still kicking in the current repo, but hasn't been updated in several years.

Comment: I'm trying to pinpoint the exact file in the AOSP source, but haven't been successful; I've only managed to locate [these layout files](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/tree/master/core/res/res/layout-sw600dp) that don't appear to be referenced anywhere.

Comment: Updated my answer with the new location in Jellybean.

Answer (score 10):

For those who are on kitkat (android 4.4) or above source code, it seems the code has been moved to

```
frameworks/base/packages/Keyguard
```