# how to write word for app on screen

Tags: android, android-widget

I want do an app,i want it look the same as this one:

[image]

I don't know how to write the word "writing" as the red mark ,and how to add the app icon on
the screen.

Comment: Do you mean you want the word "writing" to appear when the user locks the screen and your app is running or? It's really hard to tell what you're trying to do without some code or a better explaination.

Comment: I guess he wants to add an entry to the lock screen like the clock app does. ;-)

Comment: Ulkmun,you are right,i want my app hava a icon and word like the picture when the user locks the screen.

Comment: I don't have any clues,so i cannot give some code.

Comment: i want to wait some other advice,i can accept one answer,thank you for your answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is simple and yet annoying: It is not possible using the standard lock screen. [Source of Android's lock screen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2140964/android-lock-screen-source-code) describes where to find the source code of the default lock screen, and if you look into the source code of [LockScreen.java](http://android.git.kernel.org/?p=platform/frameworks/policies/base.git;a=blob_plain;f=phone/com/android/internal/policy/impl/LockScreen.java;hb=HEAD) you will find out that this information is hard coded. So basically you will have to wait for a new Android version to support this feature or program your own lock screen, which kind of misses the point. :-/

Comment: If you mean reflections: No, that will not work at all. Even for reflections you need methods that do what you desire - if they are not implemented you have no chance.

Answer (score 0):

I only found a comment in the docu [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/appwidget/package-descr.html) that it could be possible to add a widget to the lock screen sometime. Any than this I found some apps that deliver a complete alternative lock screen.

So my guess it, that the clock on your screen is only able to show the info on the lock screen due to an extra (HTC?)-API that is not available for third party developer as suggested here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3556430 too.