# Developing a custom lock screen

Tags: android, locking, screen

I want to develop custom lock screen app that looks like iPhone's lock screen.

Are there are any tutorials or examples for this? If not, where should I start?

Comment: Custom lock screens is something different from lock screen widgets. A lock screen widget is a widget that appears inside Jellybean's default lock screen.

Comment: See also [this related question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2140964/source-of-androids-lock-screen).

Comment: You may check my answer, I think will help you achieve what you want http://stackoverflow.com/a/28603790/3300883

Answer (score 22, accepted):

There is no support for creating a "custom lock screen aap" in the Android SDK. You can only modify the lock screen behavior in custom firmware.

**UPDATE**

Note that Android 4.2 *does* allow you to create app widgets that can be added to the device's lockscreen, which may meet your needs.

Comment: but i see aps in android market with iphone lock screen. how did they made it then ?

Comment: @Faisal khan: Those are not lock screens. They are either home screens with their own integrated lock mechanism, or they are ordinary applications using security flaws to pretend that they are lock screens.

Comment: yes i want to create similar home screen with custom integrative lock functionality

Comment: @Faisal khan: Then write a home screen app. There's a sample home screen app in the sample code in your Android SDK.

Comment: I'm trying to pinpoint the exact file in the AOSP source, but haven't been successful; I've only managed to locate [these layout files](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/tree/master/core/res/res/layout-sw600dp) that don't appear to be referenced anywhere. I will take a look at the actual source.

Comment: Take a look at Keyguard files somewhere in framework in the AOSP that relate to the lock screen.

Comment: Check out the Adenda SDK: http://www.adendamedia.com/