# How to customize Android's LockScreen?

Tags: android, coding-style, customization, lockscreen, unlock

I know that there is already some apps can do this, such as:

[WidgetLocker Lockscreen](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.teslacoilsw.widgetlocker)
[image]

[Flyscreen](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.flydroid.FlyScreen&feature=search_result)
[image]

I want to know how to do this in my app? What classes I can use? Or what articles I should read? I don't want to change the Android's source code.

And I wonder if it will be different to deal with when the screen is locked by draw pattern?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Developing a custom lock screen](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5529608/developing-a-custom-lock-screen)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5529608/android-how-to-develop-custom-lock-screen). You need to write your own home screen app which will implement the lockscreen behaviour that you require. There is sample code for writing your own [home screen app](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/Home/index.html) in the Android SDK.