# How can I develop an app able to actually replace lockscreen?

Tags: android, root, lockscreen

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to customize Android's LockScreen?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5829671/how-to-customize-androids-lockscreen)

How can I do lockscreen replacement, in case of rooted device? (Just the slider screen but keep the security measures)

NOT using fake method like window flag dismiss keyguard.