# Where can I find examples or tutorials about creating a custom android lockscreen?

Tags: android, lockscreen

I'm interested about Android and have been trying to find an example or tutorial about creating a custom lockscreen.

I wanna create new lock screen for easy accessibilities.

For example

- fast access to camera.
- fast access to phone dial.
- Using Speech to
  unlock screen.

I want to design the lock screen for blind people.

[This answer might be useful](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4116001/android-lock-screen-widget)

Comment: possible duplicate of [android how to develop custom lock screen](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5529608/android-how-to-develop-custom-lock-screen)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Have a look at this **[answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5529608/android-how-to-develop-custom-lock-screen)**.

You need to write your own home screen app which will implement the lockscreen behaviour that you require. There is sample code for writing your own **[home screen app in the Android SDK](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/Home/index.html)**(Source code).

Answer (score 5):

If you have the native source code, this is where Google has implemented the lock screen code

**androidgingerbread/frameworks/base/policy/src/com/android/internal/policy/impl/LockScreen.java**

This gets built into android.policy.jar.
I would say the best way to achieve what you are trying is to write a new homescreen app with required features as stated above.

Comment: This appears to be outdated, as it was last updated for Froyo. I haven't been able to find the modern variants, [except these layout files](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/tree/master/core/res/res/layout-sw600dp) which don't appear to be referenced anywhere.

Answer (score 3):

As far as I know, Google hasn't released an API that allows you to change the lock-screen on un-rooted devices.

Answer (score 1):

Lock screen widgets were deprecated in Android 5.0 and above. To help fill the void, you can use the [Adenda](http://www.adendamedia.com/) SDK. It extends the Android stack to let you design and program your layouts on the lock screen like you would with any other app, and feed them into the SDK.

For example:

```
AdendaAgent.addCustomFragmentContent (Context context, String actionToPerformOnUnlock, String your.fragment.name, Bundle fragmentArgs, String identifier, boolean bDisplayUntilCancelled)
```

I'm affiliated with Adenda for full disclosure

Comment: Just linking to your own library or tutorial is not a good answer. Linking to it, explaining why it solves the problem, providing code on how to do so and disclaiming that you wrote it makes for a better answer. See: [**What signifies “Good” self promotion?**](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/182212/200235)

Comment: Thanks for the tip @durron597. Edited accordingly

Answer (score 1):

I wrote a post about [How to write simple Android Lock Screen](http://www.thedroidboy.com/how-to-write-simple-android-lock-screen/)

In short, you can run a service that contains BroadcastReceiver that will listen to any event of `Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_OFF`, then you can draw your custom Lock Screen on top of everything by using `android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW`.