# How to create lock screen

Tags: android, lockscreen, wallpaper

I wants to create my own lock screen which replaces system lock screen with customized pictures changing each and every time locks open.
One should be able unlock screen by tapping.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Where can I find examples or tutorials about creating a custom android lockscreen?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7983143/where-can-i-find-examples-or-tutorials-about-creating-a-custom-android-lockscree)

Answer (score 4):

Here is Github source code you can find here [Source Code](https://github.com/Joisar/LockScreenApp)

Comment: Good example, But lock screen activity lagging bit. Home screen is showing bit before lock screen.