# Make your app run as Android lock screen

Tags: android, locking, screen, lockscreen

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [android lock screen source code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2140964/android-lock-screen-source-code)

I would like to know how developers have made their app run as the Android lock screen such as WidgetLocker, Screen Suit, or MyLock. People seem to know how to do this, but I have not found any tutorials for this. Is there a book or a page with tutorials? Thank you.

Comment: But the directions were broken. Is there a tutorial?

Comment: Broken how? Are you explicitly looking for a step by step?

Comment: Broken as in, the URL is 404.

Comment: Just use the [Adenda SDK](http://adendamedia.com). It essentially extends the standard Android librareis

Comment: The question pointed to as a duplicate is closed as off-topic. I guess this is incorrect, so I vote to reopen.