# Screen lock in Android

Tags: android

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Lock the Android device programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4545079/lock-the-android-device-programmatically)

Does the application have the ability to lock the screen? I have tried the following code, but nothing happens.

```
KeyguardManager keyguardManager = (KeyguardManager)getSystemService(Activity.KEYGUARD_SERVICE);
KeyguardLock lock = keyguardManager.newKeyguardLock(KEYGUARD_SERVICE);
lock.reenableKeyguard();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code looks fine and it should work..

Have you included the required permission in android manifest file.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.DISABLE_KEYGUARD" />
```

And for further reference, If you want the source code for screen lock implementation, then please check this question posted in stackoverflow and a link from android developer site.

[Source of Android's lock screen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2140964/android-lock-screen-source-code)

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/admin/device-admin.html

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/KeyguardManager.KeyguardLock.html

Comment: @ Krishna I want to lock a screen when we click on a button i use the above keyguard code and i gave the permisssion .But i did not got anything can u suggest me

Comment: @ Pinki Same code worked for me in android 1.5, I don't know about how it works in later versions.. and moreover could you please elaborate on what problem you got when trying this...