# Implement picture password in Android app

Tags: android, security

I want to secure my app using a password like on this picture:

[image: picture]
<sub>(source: [karganys.fr](https://www.karganys.fr/wp-content/uploads/2010/12/android-pattern-lock-266x400.jpg))</sub>

is there already a class that i can use or i must create by myself?
i don't find anything about this....

Comment: I don't try anything, I just would like to know if there is a allmade class that I can use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Android is open source and this is a part of Android, so the code is available. See [Source of Android's lock screen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2140964/android-lock-screen-source-code) for a link to it.