# How can i use the lock screen in my app

Tags: android, lockscreen

I need a code to use the lock screen instead of the system so that when i enter a specific password the device make the functionality that i codded it

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to implement a Lock Screen inside your app?? If so, take a look at the below links. 
[StackOverflow Discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2140964/source-of-androids-lock-screen)
[GitHub](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/tree/jb-mr1.1-release/policy/src/com/android/internal/policy/impl/keyguard)

Comment: I want my app user to set the system lock screen password from inside my app to allow him to open the lock screen and do something  else like open another app for example...
and yeah i saw this link before but i couldn't understand it